# Handle Upload File Dialog using Selenium for a Material design application

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, angular-material

I am trying to automate uploading a file in an Angular/Material design application.   Usually, one would just `SendKeys` to the input box and bypass the browser 'upload file' dialog altogether.  But, with Material design, the specific input element isn't available until after a file has been selected.  [This](http://oi68.tinypic.com/5323bo.jpg) is the source before the file selection, and [this](http://oi65.tinypic.com/2ev5a21.jpg) is the source after.  I need a way to manipulate the file upload box itself, or at the least enter text into the file selection input of that dialog box and hit enter.  I don't know if that's possible using JavaScript Execution, or some other method, but I'm at a loss.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution.  Using [this](https://nadimsaker.blogspot.com/2015/07/selenium-how-to-upload-file-in-selenium.html) documentation, I was able to add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` and manually enter the file path/name and hit the enter key.  I don't think this solution will work for anything that's not C#, but it worked really well for me.